# python generate QR code png without file output

Tags: python, png, qr-code

I am using `pypng` and `pyqrcode` for QR code image generation in django app.

```py
import os
from pyqrcode import create
import png  # pypng
import base64


def embed_QR(url_input, name):
    embedded_qr = create(url_input)
    embedded_qr.png(name, scale=7)


def getQrWithURL(url):
    name = 'url.png'
    embed_QR(url, name)
    with open(name, "rb") as image_file:
        image_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
    return image_data
```

When I call `getQrWithURL` with a url, it produces a file `url.png` to my directory. Is there a way to only get the image data without producing a file output?

---

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BytesIO` as a writable stream:

```
import io

# Make a writeable stream
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Create QR and write to buffer
embedded_qr = create(url_input)
embedded_qr.png(buffer,scale=7)


# Extract buffer contents - this is what you would get by reading a PNG disk file but without creating it
 PNG = buffer.getvalue()
```

Your variable `PNG` now contains this:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xe7\x00\x00\x00\xe7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x8f|\x8d\x00\x00\x01CIDATx\x9c\xed\x971\x92\x830\x0cE\xc5PPr\x04\x8e\x92\xa3\xc1\xd1|\x14\x8e\x90\x92\x82\xb1V_2\t\xde\xb0;i?c\x15q\xecG\xf3\x91\xfc%D\xff\x89,\x8d6\xda\xe8\x97\xf4)\x88AW\xfb\xed\xb7Q\x93\xef\'fj\x7ft\x1f\x9e\xf2Xt\xb7\xe34\x97Cb\x9a\xa43\x8a\xe3XL\xfd-\xa8\xc8\x1c\x19\xbc\x11-\xbb\x1b\xd0\xa3&m\x11\xe8\xbd\xaeX"\x1a\xbe\x01\xa1Q\x9aW\xaeBE\x8fXe\xee\xf4\x1c\xc44\xcd\x19\n\x93dX\xfcc\xb1\xcd\xc8L\x91A\x08\xb5c\xd5\xcd\x1f\xea\xb7*\xbfl\xd4\xf4\x9ao\xb8\xdeB\xbb\xd3-c\xa4h\xbc\x9dn\xa3\xd5\xa4\t\x1dW\xdf\t5\x9dt\xb1b,N\x88\xc8}\xe5\x93t\xd4\x8aQ\xa1Pp\xbd\x06\xe43\x9f\x9d\x90\x90\xfa-\xdb\xa3\xe3b\xa2\xc0Rw+6\n\',U\x18S\xdfo\xdf\xa0\xa3\x18\xf70J\xac\xf2\xea\xc6\xf5\xdb\xa0\xa3%\xdc>"\x91R\xbd\r>z\xccHq\xcb|T\xba\x98\xfa\xa8\xe8G1J\xcfN\xfd[\xc3/[x\xbbQ\x04=\x8d\xfek\x16\xafn\xf1\xfc\x14m\x18BK\xef\x9a\xa8\xa9\xd7\xa4\'\xed\xfd\x902\xd3\xf0\r\x8c\x12z\xb4\xe1\x0fW\xa1\xa2\x7fF\xa3\x8d6\xfa\x15\xfd\x01\xb9MCH#\xc3\xa2\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```